# React-Native build on device became extremely slow after switching to iMac

Tags: ios, macos, react-native, build

I'm developing a react-native application. I used to work on my personal macbook pro for a while and everything was nice and smooth. Once my macbook broke and I switched to use my company's iMac. Now it takes me a very long time only to build on a real iPhone(which was fairly quick previously), but I have no idea why.

Comment: What do you mean by "to build"? What exactly is slow?

Comment: I mean running 'Build' on Xcode in debug mode and selecting my iPhone as device. @Eduard

Comment: Acknowledged. Can't help. Probably, providing more information will help others to understand what is the problem.

Comment: If you can't provide source code, you'll need to measure.  There's lots of questions here already about Xcode build performance.

Comment: It's not a small project. But I can say I didn't write even a line of native code, it's all react and open source libraries which some have native codes. Is there anything special that might help? @Ssswift

Comment: And also @Eduard, what kind of information you are looking for?

Comment: Bat: If it's the Xcode build that's slow, have you tried any of the profiling methods for that?  I don't think you're going to find a "go fast" flag out of the blue.

Comment: It's a couple of days I'm searching the whole net for an answer. And also Xcode tweaks didn't work either. I just found out the reason is in the huge difference between ssds and usual hard disk around which I wasn't aware of. @Ssswift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the performance benchmarks of ssds and usual hard drives. Well, it's huge!! And it also answers the **TWO or THREE** times slower build time on my new machine. (not to mention that iMac uses 5400rpm hard drives, not even 7200s!)